# Best way to store user input into database and retrieve it

Tags: database, storage, phonegap-build, chatbot

I'm building a chatbot app using phonegap. I want to add some "learning" capabilities to the app, so if the user asked something that the chatbot couldn't find in it's arrays of matching keyword-answers, the system will store that particular question into a database. And in one of the future sessions, the chatbot will retrieve that question and ask the user, and will then store the response so that next time the user asks the same question the chatbot will know how to reply.

I'm new to phonegap so I'm not sure which database should I use. I've heard there SQL, SQLlite, and local storage. Which type of database will be best suited for such app?

Answer (score 0):

@michelle9090,
I recommend in the future you skim through the documentation for question like this. In addition, you are asking an architectural question, not a technical. SO is for technical questions. For architectural, I recommend [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)

Here are Links to FAQs that will help you get stated.

- There are three (3) different systems for Corodova/Phonegap [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001). People often confuse the three very similar platforms and get tangled in the minor variations that differentiate them.
- There is three (3) sets of documentation [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/), [Phonegap CLI](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/phonegap-cli), and [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/docs). They are similar, but NOT the same. Also, to add to the confusion, sometimes the Cordova documentation is the only set of docs available; this happens for some plugins.
- Phonegap is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005).

**Your Answer**
Here is a link to the 
Cordova/Phonegap [Storage Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html)